# Image overlay with css issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying put a overlay on a image. code work fine but the issue is I have another div on top of the overlay and I want the overlay to stay even when you hover that `div`

HTML

```css
.overlay {
  position: relative;
}
.overlay img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.overlay:after,
.overlay:before {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.overlay:after {
  content: '\A';
 width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.overlay:hover:after,
.overlay:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
.top-icons {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
.post-img:hover .top-icons {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-box">
    <div class="post-img">
      <div class="top-icons"><a href="">Test</a> Some text gose here</div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="overlay">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="other">

    </div>
    <!--other-->
  </div>
  <!--col-box-->
</div>
<!--col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6-->
```

I want the overlay to work even when you hover on div `top-icons`

Please check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vp1y26a3/2/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following in the css:

```css
div.post-img:hover .overlay:after, div.post-img:hover .overlay:before {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

modify yout html by making `overlay` parent of  the `top-icons`

```css
.overlay{
  position: relative;
}
.overlay img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.overlay:after,
.overlay:before {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.overlay:after {
  content: '\A';
 width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.overlay:hover:after,
.overlay:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
.top-icons {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
.post-img:hover .top-icons {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-box">
        <div class="post-img">
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="top-icons"><a href="">Test</a> Some text gose here</div>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="other">
        </div>
        <!--other-->
      </div>
      <!--col-box-->
    </div>
    <!--col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if add z-index to .`overlay::before,.overlay::after` you cant click the link that inside the div

Comment: +1 this work but im marking @mihkov answer as correct because if i change the HTML i can have a link on overlay. because it is not allowed to have a link inside another link. But thanks. Your awesome.

Comment: @max you have two separate links inside your `.overlay ` using my snippet, that's valid. they aren't inside one of another ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS rule 
    `.overlay:hover:after, .overlay:hover:before`

just change it with `.post-img:hover .overlay:after, .post-img:hover .overlay:before`